# Criar navbar com campo de pequisa centralizado

Tags: html, css, nav-bar

esto tentando fazer um nav bar com um campo de pesquisa centralizado..
eu até consegui fazer mais acredito não estar da melhor forma, pois quando abro em um smartphone fica tudo estranho...

Segue abaixo meu código.

```
 <div class="top_nav">
        <div class="nav_menu">
          <nav>
            <div class="nav toggle">
              <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
            </div>

            <!-- campo para pesquisa-->
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="listaProcessos.html">
              <div class="input-group" style="margin: 4px 0 0 250px; width:400px">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar">
                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="color:#5A738E"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <!--fim campo de pesquisa-->


          </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Coloca teu css, fica mais fácil de te ajudar

Comment: Por acaso vc está usando Bootstrap? Se sim qual Versão?

Comment: A versão do bootstrap é v3.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tente usar:**

style="padding: 0 10% 0 10%;"

**no lugar de:**

style="margin: 4px 0 0 250px; width:400px"

você pode ajustar o padding em porcentagem para deixar o input de pesquisa no tamanho desejado.

Comment: pra mim isso já foi o suficiente, valeu man.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utiliza o seguinte código para centralizar, mas deve ter outro elemento no final para que tenha o alinhamento dos 3:

```
display: flex
justify-content: space-between
```

Código de funcionamento:

https://codepen.io/gabrielgoncalvesr/pen/eLWByR

> Veja outros [exemplos de utilização](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/).

Você pode também tenta fazer com sistema de grid do Bootstap, mas não sei se é o mais adequado para um navbar.

Código de funcionamento:

https://codepen.io/gabrielgoncalvesr/pen/GXmNeK

Comment: Jovem só que ele está usando o Bootstrap 3... E mesmo se foce o 4 vc poderia usar as classes nativas do framewark tipo d-flex, justify-content-center,  w-100 como vc pode consultar aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/